# Ionic 3 App Stuck on Loading Screen Randomly

Tags: uiwebview, ionic3

```
Ionic: 3.19.0
Node: 7.7.1
Cordova-ios: 4.5.4, 4.1.0, 4.4.0
```

The app gets stuck on the loading screen randomly. Mostly it happens if I force close the app and open it after an hour. 
On the safari developer menu, whenever that happens it only shows about: blank and not localhost as it does when the app loads properly.
Current config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="180604" id="com.globetrekkerchallenge.app" ios-CFBundleVersion="180604" version="4.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>XXX</name>
    <description>
        XXX
    </description>
    <author email="XXX" href="">
        XXX
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="ParseNotificationIcon" />
    <preference name="ParseAppId" value="XXX" />
    <preference name="ParseServerUrl" value="XXX" />
    <preference name="ParseGcmSenderId" value="XXX" />
    <preference name="ParseAutoRegistration" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Keyboard">
            <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard" />
        </feature>
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.4.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mixpanel" spec="^4.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.8.15" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="parse-push-plugin" spec="git+https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crop" spec="^0.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.6.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notifications-ios10" spec="^0.8.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="^0.8.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-streaming-media" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia" />
    <plugin name="com.telerik.plugins.healthkit" spec="~0.5.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="~1.3.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Really scratching my head over this issue. Can someone help me with this.
If I run the app from Xcode it loads fine always so no way to debug.
In the console of Xcode Organiser and Devices I dont even see the following when the issue happens.

```
Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the ionic-cordova-webview plugin. It crashes when there is a background push notifications.